# How is 向 pronounced in 男性向同人?

Tags: readings, abbreviations, okurigana

Different sources have given me different pronunciations.

I figured it must mean "Doujin aimed at males", but if that's the case, from what I know, it should be written [男性向け同人]{だんせいむけどうじん}。
Is 男性向 an abbreviation, and still pronounced だんせいむけ, despite the け not being there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, 男性向 is a valid abbreviation, and still pronounced だんせいむけ. *Okurigana* is often omitted, especially in longer compounds like 男性向同人.

Similar examples:

- 受け付け = 受付け = 受付 = うけつけ ("reception")
- 申し込み = 申込み = 申込 = もうしこみ ("application")
- 打ち合わせ = 打合せ = うちあわせ ("meeting")

Omission of okurigana is largely customary and happens in limited number of words. Please don't try to omit okurigana freely.