# What is the difference between spellings of 組み付ける?

Tags: words, spelling

I'm reading some technical documents and have come across two spellings:

組み付ける
and
組付ける

Both are used in nearly identical situations and both seem to mean "assemble" as a directive. Is there a particular reason to omit (or include) み？

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called 送り仮名の省略. Both are the same, and usually neither is more correct.

- [有り難う vs 有難う — Is this the same word?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/42093/5010)
- [How is 向 pronounced in 男性向同人?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38845/5010)
- [公文書用語　送り仮名が省略される複合語](http://mbp-okayama.com/kikuchi/column/7634/)

Of course you should stick to one spelling throughout the document, so in this sense it's a small mistake. There may be a 送り仮名 convention depending on the field or the style guideline of the publisher.