# Grammaticality of two kanji verbs without their conjugating part

Tags: kanji, verbs, conjugations, nouns, renyōkei

A friend told me he's going to get a tattoo with "頑張".

頑張 doesn't exist on the dictionary without its -る conjugating part, so is it grammatically correct using it alone, as if it was a noun? Does it make any sense? More generally, does it make any sense omitting the conjugating part from a two (or more) kanji verb and using it as a noun? Wouldn't it be better to use the 連用形 form? Should I suggest my friend to rather get a "頑張り" tattoo?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, choosing a different *noun/suru-verb* with a similar meaning and on-reading (e.g., 努力, 研鑽, 全力, 精進, 鍛錬...) should always be a better option. Does he really need this "mundane" kun-reading word?

Next, 頑張 is of course not grammatical in ordinary sentences. But in this case, if you absolutely need to use this word and feel adding non-kanji り (or る) is aesthetically displeasing, [okurigana omission](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/38846/5010) might be applied, although it's far from conventional and should be considered as a last resort. This type of nonstandard okurigana omission is occasionally seen in 必殺技 names of a battle manga (e.g., 斬【ぎり】 instead of 斬り, 蹴【げり】 instead of 蹴り). Place names usually do not have okurigana, either (e.g., 夕張【ゆうばり】市 and 幕張【まくはり】).

<sub>(I would rather not repeat how Japanese people see those kanji tattoos here, but if this tattoo may be seen by Japanese people, please take time and do some research.)</sub>

Comment: "I would rather not repeat how Japanese people see those kanji tattoos here" --> Please do it, I am really curious about it. (Anyway, my friend finally decided to get a tattoo with 勝ち気)